# SUM of the result of a subquery

Tags: sql, sum, subquery

I have a subquery which outputs a column of numbers, and I want to add the sum of that column and to an element in the main query.

```
...
...
DSR_SEGMENT_LIGNE.SEG_R0 + (

select DSR_MUTUELLES.MUT_R0M
    from DSR_SEGMENT_LIGNE
    inner join DSR_NOEUD_SIMUL
        on DSR_SEGMENT_LIGNE.SEG_ID_NOEUD_DEPART = DSR_NOEUD_SIMUL.NOE_ID_NOEUD
    inner join DSR_NOEUD_SIMUL DSR_NOEUD_SIMUL_ARRIVEE
        on DSR_SEGMENT_LIGNE.SEG_ID_NOEUD_ARRIVEE = DSR_NOEUD_SIMUL_ARRIVEE.NOE_ID_NOEUD
    inner join DSR_LIGNE
        on DSR_LIGNE.LIG_ID_LIGNE = DSR_SEGMENT_LIGNE.LIG_ID_LIGNE
    inner join DSR_SECTION_LIGNE
        on DSR_SEGMENT_LIGNE.SEG_ID_SEGMENT = DSR_SECTION_LIGNE.SEG_ID_SEGMENT
    inner join DSR_MUTUELLES
        on DSR_MUTUELLES.SEC_ID_SECTION = DSR_SECTION_LIGNE.SEC_ID_SECTION
    where DSR_SEGMENT_LIGNE.SEG_NOM = "B" 
    and DSR_LIGNE.LIG_NOM = "3040"
    group by SUP_ID_SUPPORT_FIN
    having count(*) = 1 

) as "r0",
...
...
```

I have tried `select sum(DSR_MUTUELLES.MUT_R0M)` but the result is still the column of numbers. How can I fix this?

Edit: the result is

```
MUT_R0M
====================
0,000440189590797144
0,00058993549817939
0,000386024704379443
0,00213515586191037
0,00132871690706617
0,000612226166725588
```

and I need the result to be

```
MUT_R0M
=============
0.00549224873
```

Comment: CAn you edit your question with the result of the subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(DSR_MUTUELLES.MUT_R0M)
FROM (

 select DSR_MUTUELLES.MUT_R0M
from DSR_SEGMENT_LIGNE
inner join DSR_NOEUD_SIMUL
    on DSR_SEGMENT_LIGNE.SEG_ID_NOEUD_DEPART
        = DSR_NOEUD_SIMUL.NOE_ID_NOEUD
inner join DSR_NOEUD_SIMUL DSR_NOEUD_SIMUL_ARRIVEE
    on DSR_SEGMENT_LIGNE.SEG_ID_NOEUD_ARRIVEE
        = DSR_NOEUD_SIMUL_ARRIVEE.NOE_ID_NOEUD
inner join DSR_LIGNE
    on DSR_LIGNE.LIG_ID_LIGNE
        = DSR_SEGMENT_LIGNE.LIG_ID_LIGNE
inner join DSR_SECTION_LIGNE
    on DSR_SEGMENT_LIGNE.SEG_ID_SEGMENT
        = DSR_SECTION_LIGNE.SEG_ID_SEGMENT
inner join DSR_MUTUELLES
    on DSR_MUTUELLES.SEC_ID_SECTION
        = DSR_SECTION_LIGNE.SEC_ID_SECTION
where DSR_SEGMENT_LIGNE.SEG_NOM = "B" and DSR_LIGNE.LIG_NOM = "3040"
group by SUP_ID_SUPPORT_FIN
having count(*) = 1 
) as "r0"...
```

Comment: Thanks it works flawlessly! (actually I had to replace `SELECT SUM(DSR_MUTUELLES.MUT_R0M)` with `SELECT SUM(MUT_R0M)`)